# Is there a bug with the rally API when querying release dates?

Tags: rally

I think there is a bug when querying a release's ReleaseDate field. Let's say I have a release with a ReleaseDate of 04/24/2017 EDT, when I get the response from the API request, and take a peek at the ReleaseDate field for that release, it comes off as 04/25/2017 (in date time format obviously), one day ahead of the actual date. I am building a calendar app for inside use using full calendar, and this bug is really annoying. Am I correct to say that this is a bug? Are there any workarounds that do not involve writing code to fix the date after querying it? thanks.

Comment: Also, when updating the field using the API, if I pass a value like 04/25/2017 as the new value, it also updates it with one day off, this time one day behind, so the stored value would be 04/24/2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure this is timezone related.  Dates in WSAPI are always UTC.  Assuming your workspace is configured for Eastern the dates returned probably are the next day:

A release with an end date of 04/24/2017 is probably being returned from WSAPI with a date like `2017-04-25T03:59:59.000Z`, which when converted to EDT would be the end of the day on the 24th.

You'll also want to be specific when setting dates since the backend will again try to coerce the date into UTC if there is no time specified.  The current behavior or the detail pages is to set it to noon on that day for that timezone.  So something like this: `2017-04-24T12:00:00-05:00`

Hope that helps.  We did a bunch of work across the product and the api's last year to try to provide a more consistent experience working with timezones.  It still can be confusing, but a good rule of thumb is to always be specific and include a time and timezone offset when working with dates using the api.

If you're using App SDK, the moment.js library is already included and is super handy for working with dates:
https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/guide/third_party_libs-section-moment.js-2.10.3

Comment: That was it. Cheers.